# Select a value on a dropbox list when user clicks on a checkbox? (In the same view) Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have defined an extended product view which uses a checkbox field to define that a product has certain attributes.

I would like that when user clicks on that checkbox a given value in Units of Measure dropdown field is automatically selected.

So, how do I select a value on a dropdown list when user clicks on a checkbox? (same view).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be done by onchange method. You can define new boolean fields in that model and need to write onchange function for that.

```
@api.onchange('boolean_field1','boolean_field2')
def onchange_boolean(self):
    if self.boolean_field:
        self.product_uom_id = product_uom_record_id
    else:
        self.product_uom_id = product_uom_record_id
    #Your custom code
```

> Here,
>
> **product_uom_record_id** : you need to search product uom record and set it there. Make sure you must assign ID not the object (browsable
>   record)

By this way you can call this function while onchange happen on this boolean field.

Comment: Thanks, it is the first time I interact with select dropdown lists. What shall be used in "your_value"? I mean, I would like to select a specific value I added. Can you assign value just using the name or do you have to use the key?